# intent to launch map with placemarks in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I saved some placemarks in a map in Google Maps-"my Places" and I want to launch it with an intent.
I can launch Google Maps and center it with coordinates, but I can't load the placemarks I have in my map.
This is the code I use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
             Uri.parse(myMap));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", 
                     com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

startActivity(intent);
```

If I use the following link in the browser, I can see detail of the selected placemark, but using it from intent i see no placemarks, just the map:

https://www.google.com/maps/ms?msid=206212653941099478857.0004e6e21f640cfa6a5fa&msa=0&ll=43.329124,11.322522&spn=0.002191,0.00408&iwloc=0004e6e23273981581522

How can I see the map with relative placemarks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an Intent issue I don't think.

Try this link, it is a bit more involved in android:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Also this link has an example:

[code to add markers to map using android google maps v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194918/code-to-add-markers-to-map-using-andorid-google-maps-v2)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'd prefer not to write a GoogleMap application, I'd like just to use something I edited once for all on Google Map web.

Comment: Yes, it loads properly on a webview (even if there is a problem passing parameters to a webview addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238277/url-with-parameter-in-webview-not-working-in-android)