# PHP Fatal error: Function name must be a string

Tags: php

```
    $img1 = $_GET['img1'];
    $img2 = $_GET['img2'];
    $query = $mysql_query("SELECT * FROM asd WHERE ID=$img1");
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $query = $mysql_query("SELECT * FROM asd WHERE ID=$img2");
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

--

Was having trouble with this, forgot to exclude $

Comment: Would you restore the original version? That way it may help someone else in the future. As it stands, it is only good for closing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$query = $mysql_query("SELECT * FROM asd WHERE ID=$img1");
```

and here:

```
$query = $mysql_query("SELECT * FROM asd WHERE ID=$img2");
```

Remove the '$' before `mysql_query(...);`

Comment: awww goddamit, thank you!

Comment: Sleep coding: it happens to us all.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing mysql_query as a variable by prefixing it with the '$'. try removing the dollar to call the mysql_query function.