# fetching get parameter in webview for android 4.0.0

Tags: android, url, webview, android-assets

I have a webview inside my main activity and I load the page using:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/images/index.html?rows=5&columns=5");
```

And it is working on Android 4.4.2 either hardware or emulator.

Lately I tried running it on 4.0.3 or 4.0.0 and I get an error:

```
webpage not available.
```

I have found that the get parameters are the reason for the problem.

How to pass variables to a webpage in webview ?

I am using this code to fetch the get parameters:

```
 function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
 }
```

Comment: Same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238277/url-with-parameter-in-webview-not-working-in-android

Comment: No. The bug I am talking about is related to `file:///` only.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

Comment: It is the same. The stackoverflow link even links to the same issue.