# JS URL API not working in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, url, android-webview

I want to get parameters in the URL to show message according to paramters but this not working in android WebView.

```
// JS in webview web page
// document.location = https://www.test.com?login=true
var url_string = document.location;
var url = new URL(url_string);

// url.searchParams.get('login') gives true
if (url.searchParams.get("login") === 'true') {
    $('#login-modal').modal('show');
}
```

Any helpful solutions and answers will be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and show what the URL is and how you are using it with the `WebView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare have edited!

Comment: have you enabled javascript in your webview by default its not enabled use `webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: So you are using Bootstrap and JQuery? How do you link to the libaries? By CDN?

Comment: If you are loading a file from your assets, it may be a victim of a known WebView bug (see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36929511 for the full report). You may also want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238277/url-with-parameter-in-webview-not-working-in-android for some solutions to the same root issue.